# Gnuplot - script internal error, but when I write it normally it works, but script not

Tags: gnuplot

I don't know why but I have an error. When I write all this things in terminal everything is ok, but when I use script I have this error

```
gnuplot> load wykres_sin.gp 
         internal error : STRING operator applied to undefined or non-STRING variable
```

This is my script

```
# Skrypt gnuplot

plot sin(x) w l
set title "Wykres sinusa od wartosci kata"
set xlabel "Wartosc kata (stopnie)"
set ylabel "Wartość sinusa"
set xrange [0:750]
set yrange [-1.2:1.2]
set term png large size 800,600
set output "sin.png"
replot
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around the file name:

```
 gnuplot> load "wykres_sin.gp"
```